# print JSON string converted from python object using flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I have this flask server running and i made this html file which has a script where when i clicked the button it will return a JSON string. However it kept giving me undefined instead.
I have this app.py code which gives me a python dict which i converted it to JSON

```
@app.route('/')
def helloworld():
    #result = jsonify(student)
    html_item = json.dumps(Marks, indent=2, separators=(', ', ': '))
    return render_template('test1.html',data = html_item)
```

after this on the test1.html i have a script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>  
            JavaScript | Print content of object 
        </title> 
    </head>  

    <body style = "text-align:center;" id = "body">  

        <h1 style = "color:rgb(0, 2, 128);" >  
           {{data}}
        </h1> 

        <p> 
            Print JavaScript Object. 
        </p> 

        <button onclick = "gfg_Run()">  
            print object 
        </button> 

        <p id = "GFG_DOWN" style 
                = "color:rgb(0, 2, 128); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"> 
        </p> 

        <script> 
            var el_down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN"); 

            var GFG_object = { 
                prop_1: 'val_11', 
                prop_2: 'val_12',  
                prop_3: 'val_13' 
            }; 

            function gfg_Run(data) {  
                el_down.innerHTML = data;
                //el_down.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(GFG_object); 
            } 

        </script>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

where I have tested that it can print out a js object by the line I commented out.
How should I print out a JSON string which in my case `data`properly?

Comment: *What* gives you undefined?

Comment: if you are trying to render in your json string into your html template show that attempt. I don't see where you try to use `html_item`, assuming `render_template` should be replacing something in `test1.html` with whatever is in `html_item`. For instance in a flask template i would expect to see something like `GFG_object = {{ html_item }}`

Comment: @DanielRoseman after I clicked the button i got undefined

Comment: @PatrickEvans what do you mean by doing ```GFG_object = {{ html_item }}``` in flask template, in the python file you mean?

Comment: You haven't even shown a button. Neither did you say *where* you "got undefined". What **exactly** do you see?

Comment: Meant `GFG_object = {{ data }}` but you have `render_template('test1.html',data = html_item)` so your html file `test1.html` is being used as a flask template. In which variables that are in the template like `{{ data }}` get replaced with what you passed to render_template

Comment: @DanielRoseman i just updated my full version of html page like i said i had the undefined thing after i clicked the button and below the button it displayed as such.

Comment: @PatrickEvans
wouldn't it be necessary to include ```data``` in ```render_template()``` so that i can use the variable in the html page?

Comment: Yes that is what i am saying, but you aren't using it correctly, see the [answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58933083/560593)

Comment: "I had the undefined thing" does not explain anything. **Where does it say undefined, exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering your json string in your html template

Just having the word `data` is not going to take the `data` variable from your python script and replace it with your json. You need it surrounded in curly braces `{{}}`

```
//incorrect
myobject = data;
//correct
myobject = {{ data|safe }};
```

So to get your example working you could do

```
var GFG_object = {{data|safe}};

//took out the "data" from the parameter list
//since you aren't passing anything to gfg_Run()
function gfg_Run() {  
  //prints your object as a json string
  el_down.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(GFG_object);
}

//if you are wanting print some property of your object
function gfg_Run() {  
  el_down.innerHTML = GFG_object["val"];
}
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion however now it doesn't show up any thing after i clicked the button, did i missed anything?

Comment: @WeisuXiong Neither example worked? ie the JSON.stringify() nor the other? Did you check for errors in the javascript console? If you have no errors there then are you using the right property name? I only used `"val"` as an example. You would use the name of whatever property you are trying to use.

Comment: yes I will find out a way to check erros in js console as I am still new. I only tried the first one as I intend to print everything in my object. My data looks like this
``` {
  "George": "0095",
  "Kelly": "0100",
  "Mike": "0087",
  }
```

Comment: @WeisuXiong For checking errors just hit F12 key and it will open developer tools in your browser and hit the console tab. Errors will show up in red.

Comment: the error is this
```(index):19 Uncaught ReferenceError: gfg_Run is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):19)
onclick @ (index):19
```

Comment: Any other errors? As that means your `gfg_Run` function didnt get defined. And the only way that would happen with your code is if some earlier error prevented it.

Comment: Actually the error i said was after i clicked the button. If i refresh the page another two error came out 
```(index):31 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'
(index):1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Comment: where line 31 is this
```
var GFG_object = {
  &#34;George&#34;: &#34;0095&#34;, 
```

Comment: Oh flask is encoding the string to prevent harmful code injection use the `|safe` to prevent that so it would be `{{ data|safe }}`

Comment: Thanks so much. I figured out this as well. However i still have this error
```(index):1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```
will this matters?

Comment: If your button now works then that error is for something else which I have no idea about. Seems like it might be from a browser extension so that wouldn't have anything to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you should know how to retrieve json data?! 
If not, then visit: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json

Now that you know how to retrieve data stored in json format, and you should put the value straight into inner_html like:

```
el_down.innerhtml = data['val']
```

Or however, your json structure might be... 
I think the way you are accessing json data is not correct. Please let me know after you try this solution.

Comment: i try testing if my data is a JSON string by putting it in like```<h1>data</h1>```, so wouldn't that suggest my data is already a JSON string?

Comment: No, that is not how it works. If you want to check the type of data, put `type(data)`. This will display the type of the data. But if you are rendering it on to a template. It won't work. For rendering on to a template you need to put `{{ type(data) }}`

Comment: but i dont think ```el_down.innerhtml = data['val'] ``` is working. Could you explain why my JSON string not printing?